# How to install an application which size is bigger than 1MB on s40 device?

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish, nokia-s40

I am developing a J2ME application. Its size is 1.5MB.

When I try to install it using Nokia PC Suite, this error appears "  the application cannot be installed to the phone the file size is too big".

How may I install this application or any way to decrease its size?

Comment: What is the phone model? Do you know what is the maximum jar size the phone can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used proguard to obfuscate and optimize the jar file?
Are there resources (image, video, sound...) in the jar file that you could download as a background task when the user launches the applications?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download uc browser in your phone
   .
2. Then download your app with uc browser's downloader.
   .
3. It will save your app as name_jar.
   .
4. Exit uc browser.
   .
5. Went to directary, where you downloaded the app.
   .
6. Now rename your file from name_jar to name.jar.

.
.
Thats all now run the app.

Answer (score 0):

try to decrease the size by using low res images, sounds like jpg or mp3 and use obfuscation, it will decrease the space of jar and also set maximum jar size in emulator settings.